# Nested awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with this syntax:

```
foo:bar:value1,value2,value3,...:foo:bar
```

I want to get the value list (space separated) which does not have a fixed length:

```
value1 value2 value3 ...
```

Is there a way to do this in a single awk command ? Instead of piping commands like that:

```
awk -F: '{print $3}' myfile.txt | awk -F, '{OFS=" "; $1 = $1; print $0}'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know which field to grab the csv separated values, then you can use `gsub` function too:

```
awk -F: '{gsub(/,/," ",$3);print $3}' file
```

```
$ cat file
foo:bar:value1,value2,value3,value3:foo:bar
foo:bar:value1,value2:foo:bar
foo:bar:value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6:foo:bar
```

```
$ awk -F: '{gsub(/,/," ",$3);print $3}' file
value1 value2 value3 value3
value1 value2
value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for: short and efficient

Comment: @twalberg yea, but would make it less portable since `gensub` is `gawk` only.

Comment: gsub has only three params: regexp, replacem., target. Why 4?

Comment: @Timo Correct gsub has three. He was referring to gensub in comments.

Comment: @jaypal `gsub(/,/," ",$3)`, 4 params?!

Comment: @Timo thats three param. First is a regular expression which uses , as an expression.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Awk's `split()` function to do additional splitting.

```
awk -F : '{ split($3, a, ","); print a[1], a[2], a[3] }' file
```

Comment: +1, note the updated questions states that there is no fixed length. For this, you can use `n=split()` to catch the number of elements and then loop `for (i=1; i<=n; ...)` printing the values of `a[]`.

Comment: Thanks guys. It is working like a charm with this: `awk -F : '{ n=split($3, a, ","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i] }' myfile.txt`